# How to run react-native application from android studio and specify --mode= flag?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

Im trying to run RN application from android studio and it works ok, but I need react-native run-android --mode=stagingdebug instead of just react-native run-android

How can I do that?

I have tried to add --mode=stagingdebug in configuration flags, but I got error:

```
Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --mode=stagingdebug --skip-verification -S 28237666' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install-create':
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown option --mode=stagingdebug

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just add this flag to the "flags" box.

Take a look at this in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig

Just pass the flag you want.

But, you are running in the `/android` folder right?
Because when you run a react native project in the android studio, the IDE does not run "react-native run android", the gradlew is used istead

Comment: Thanks but I tried to add --mode=stagingdebug and got error.

Comment: Please, @AlmaG3st, can you update the question with the steps that you did and show the error?

Comment: Just updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find it, at left bottom side, there is dropdown: Build Variants, thats where you can choose it.